# Limit Openfire login attempts

Tags: security, xmpp, firewall, openfire

I can try to login openfire account as many times as I want. How can I set a login attempts limit. Such as after 10 attempts blocking the ip address, or blocking the user, or deleting the user?         Can I edit the source code or is there such a plugin?

Comment: i've never seen such plugin

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such a plugin, but you can take a look here:

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/admin/LoginLimitManager.html

This class handles the issue you have addressed.